# Open SharePoint List using GUID in URL

Tags: url, sharepoint-2007, guid, custom-lists

I need to open a SharePoint list in a browser using the RootSite, List GUID, and/or View GUID. Is there a way to do this?

I am assuming that the URL would look something like:

`http://rootsite/_vti_bin?LIST={7F1BA68C-8D94-48D7-BF97-AC5C6FF0665A}`

Any ideas? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: from a remote program ? from a browser ? from a local running application ? From a sharepoint application directly ?

Comment: I am opening the link via Visual Basic and the only information I have available is the information above. Thank you!